# How to replace URL resource path with regex?

Tags: regular-expression

I am trying to write a regular expression that will match a link-attribute in .png  files.

Example: I have a lot of .png like this

```
https://jnTb6EZom8c/s144/800px-s%25252Ct%252529%2520%25282%2529.png
https://jnTb6EZom8c/s1300/800px-s%25252Ct%252529%2520%25282%2529.png
https://jnTb6EZom8c/s50/800px-s%25252Ct%252529%2520%25282%2529.png
```

I want to search for `/s144` `/s1300` `/s50` and so on and replace it with `/s400+c`. My Regex `/\/s\B\d{2,4}/` works fine in Regex-Tester.

Now I want to do the job with vim, but I always get 'pattern not found'. What is wrong with my regular-expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few problems with your version. `/` needs to be backslash escaped in the Vim find command line*, and `{2,4}` type repeats also need a preceding backslash. The `\B` zero-width non-word boundary atom does not exist in Vim-flavour regular expressions, but I don't think it's actually required for your purpose, anyway.

Try `/\/s\d\{2,4}/`

See `:help pattern-overview` for details of Vim's regular expressions.

<sub>* Note that in other contexts, such as in an `:s` command, you can use almost any non-alphanumeric character as a regular expression delimiter. If you want to include `/` characters in your expression, just use a different character for your delimiter.</sub>

Comment: `/\/s\d{2,4}/`is not working for me, but `/\/s\d\{2,4}/` works fine! Thanks for help.

Comment: You're right! I've updated my answer.